# Leap year algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, ruby, datetime

I wrote two functions for determining leap years.
("Kabisat" means "leap year" in Indonesia.)

```
def kabisat? y
  return false if y%4!=0   
  return true if y%100!=0  
  y%400==0                 
end

def kabisat_2? y
  return true if y%400==0   
  return false if y%100==0  
  y%4==0                    
end 

require 'date';

(1..Date.today.year).each { |y|
  puts y if kabisat?(y)!=kabisat_2?(y)
}
```

Is it correct? And it is possible to write a shorter one?

Comment: Why not use the built-in [`Date#leap?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-leap-3F) method?

In any event, your `kabisat_1` function is broken. It'll return `true` for, say, 2013, because it's not divisible by 100. But 2013 certainly isn't a leap year.

Comment: no it is not? kabisat? 2013 == false

Comment: Yes, your method checks `y%4!=0` first, so it'll return the right thing. But reversing the checks is suspect. The logic is that "if a year _is_ divisible by 100, it's _not_ a leap year". But that does not mean, that every year that _isn't_ divisible automatically _is_ a leap year. I.e. the check against 100 can only can only tell you if something's _not_ a leap year; it can't tell you if it is.

Comment: You should test it with some corner cases, e.g. 1900, 2000, 2004.

Comment: Why don't u google? http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Leap_year#Ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notes:

- I assume that, for some reason, you want to write your own function/method instead of the existing [Date#leap?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-leap-3F) that @Flambino linked above.
- `kabisat?` We all love our mother tongue, but in computing English is the lingua franca, specially when you share your code with people around the world. It's a nice word to learn, though :-)
- This is a personal advice, not all Ruby programmers agree: don't use inline returns. Use the good old full-fledged conditionals, it's much more clear. In general, use expressions instead of statements.

Let's see the standard [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm). Ok, I'll just translate it to Ruby (if I felt fancy I'd even add `Integer#divisible_by?(n)` for a fully declarative code):

```
def is_leap_year?(year)
  if year % 400 == 0 
    true
  elsif year % 100 == 0
    false
  elsif year % 4 == 0
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Too verbose? use boolean logic:

```
def is_leap_year?(year)
  (year % 400 == 0) || (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0)
end
```

Comment: i like the boolean logic :3